# How can I change the number of errors GCC displays without invaliding the CMake cache?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, compiler-errors, c++20

I have a C++ project that I build using GCC and CMake.

Generally I like to compile with `-fmax-errors=1`.  My normal workflow is to fix the first error and then rebuild since subsequent errors are often caused by the first one.

But unfortunately, with C++20, an error involving a constraint failure is often treated as multiple "errors" by GCC.  In order to see why the constraint failed, I need to see more than one error.

So occasionally I like to set `-fmax-errors` to a higher number, probably `2`, when such an error occurs.

But changing the compiler flags (by manually changing `CMakeLists.txt` or passing a cache variable to `cmake` on the command line) invalidates the CMake cache and makes the build start from scratch.

This behavior generally makes sense of course; arbitrary configuration changes could require a rebuild.  But we humans understand that changing the compiler's error-formatting behavior doesn't require a rebuild.  Is there a way of expressing this distinction to CMake?

Or, failing that, is there a clever way of working around this?  I thought of having CMake read an environment variable at the time when the compiler is invoked (not at the time when `cmake` is run), but I can't find any documentation suggesting that this is actually possible.

(I could probably create a script that forwards most of its arguments to `g++` but also adds `-fmax-errors="$MY_COOL_ENV_VARIABLE"` and then tell CMake that the script in question is the C++ compiler to build with, but I imagine that this might violate some of CMake's expectations about the "compiler.")

Comment: Your last suggestion about a script looks quite common to me, I don't think it violates any expectation.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, good thought!  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the advice of Marc Glisse, I gave the approach that I hypothesized in parentheses at the end of the question a try.  This in fact works quite well.

I now have a Python script called `invoke_compiler.py` in the top-level directory of my project.  I point CMake to the script in the usual way in which one specifies a C++ compiler.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/invoke_compiler.py)
```

Now I was actually a bit terse in the question for the sake of exposition.  In actuality I regularly build this project with both GCC and Clang.  So I want to be able to specify the C++ compiler to CMake when I invoke `cmake`.

```
cmake my-src-dir -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++
```

So `invoke_compiler.py` has to take a few extra command-line flags, `--my-project-cxx-compiler` and `--my-project-num-errors-flag`.

Then the script invokes the compiler (whose executable is the one specified by `--my-project-cxx-compiler`), forwarding all of its command-line arguments except the extra ones mentioned above and adding `f"{num_errors_flag}={os.environ.get('MY_PROJECT_NUM_ERRORS', 1)}"`.  (The name of the compiler flag specifying the number of errors to display must itself be passed as an argument to the script because GCC and Clang call the flag `--fmax-errors` and `--ferror-limit` respectively.)

The trick is simply that the logic in `CMakeLists.txt` that determines which arguments to pass to `invoke_compiler.py` needs to execute before `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is overwritten.

The user just interacts with CMake as usual and changes the value of the `MY_PROJECT_NUM_ERRORS` variable at any time in order to get a different number of errors from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The way below does not require changing your CMakeLists.txt and other source files or invalidating CMake cache. It is somewhat *hackish*, but should work when **CMake is used with make as buildsystem and GCC compilers**. It uses the `--` CMake command line argument to pass additional arguments to the underlying build tool (which is make in our case). It also uses the `-e` flag of make to make it prefer environment variables over local makefile assignments.

```
CXX_FLAGS="... -fmax-errors=1" cmake --build <dir> -- -e
```

Instead of `...` you should pass what is currently being assigned to the CXX_FLAGS variable in the makefiles generated for current CMake build configuration. To find that out you can either investigate the generated makefiles or try to run something like

```
cmake --build <dir> -- -pn | grep ^CXX_FLAGS
```

which tells underlying make to avoid actual building, but print some info instead, including assigning of variables, which in turn we then grep for the needed assignment.

E.g. in my case running the command above prints

```
CXX_FLAGS = -g -fPIC   -Wno-deprecated -pthread
```

So I need to run

```
CXX_FLAGS="-g -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden   -Wno-deprecated -pthread -fmax-errors=1" cmake --build <dir> -- -e
```

to limit the GCC compilation errors to only one.

P.S.: The `CXX_FLAGS` variable name seems to not be documented and is probably CMake implementation detail and can probably be changed in the future. In that case you'll need to investigate the generated makefiles to get the needed variable name.